# Currently we are using IE on Windows phone 7, can we use mozilla or safari instead?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Currently we are using Internet explorer on windows phone 7, instead can we use Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox or Safari?

Answer (score 1):

At this stage neither Mozilla or Apple have made a port of their browser to WP7.

If they did they'd either need to deal with native to managed translation or enter an agreement with Microsoft to develop as a 1st/2nd party effort.

I won't speculate as to the likelyhood of any of this taking place.

Answer (score 0):

Since Microsoft only expose APIs in C#/Silverlight, and firefox/safari/chrome are coded by C/C++. So I don't think it can port to Windows Phone 7, unless Microsoft expose its Native API in C/C++.